# Comparación de dos strings iguales en jquery se evaluan como distintos

Tags: jquery, string, comparaciones

Tengo dos **strings**, uno que recojo desde un campo *input* y otro que recojo desde un *json*, recorriendolo y comparando con cada uno de los strings que contiene. Muestro la compración en la consola y obtengo lo siguiente:

**1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0** y **1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0**

Pero aún así los evalua como diferentes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  if (data[i][column] == term){
    alert("iguales");
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el JSON relacionado?

Comment: probaste añadiendo trim()?. data[i][column].trim() == term.trim()

Comment: cual es el formato del json ? porque alli veo que muestras numeros separados por un punto, pero eso no es json

Comment: Efectivamente se trataba de un problema de espacios en blanco.

Comment: @ArielOctavioD'Alfeo creo que estaría bien que agregues tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como lo respondí en comentarios, faltaría añadir trim() para eliminar los espacios.

```
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {        
  if (data[i][column].trim() == term.trim()){
    alert("iguales");
  }
}
```